# How to disable specific dates in calendar

Tags: android, calendar

How can I disable specific dates? I don't mean previous or future dates, but rather specified dates such as holidays.

Comment: can you elaborate more what do you mean by disable and where do you want them to disable??

Comment: all the very best and please ask if you have any issues.

Comment: it should not be able to select in calendar

Answer (score 3):

> How to disable specific dates in calendar

**AFAIK** No You can't disable specific dates in calendar because that is 
That is not a built in behavior

for that purpose you have to use third party library or your have to create your own

you would have to use a custom date picker.

Comment: can u please send me a code to disable specific date like this               List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();
                dates.add(26-07-2017);
                dates.add(25-07-2017);
                dates.add(17-09-2015);
                dates.add(25-09-2015);
                dates.add(27-09-2015);
                dates.add(13-10-2015);
                dates.add(22-10-2015);
                Calendar[] disabledDays1 = dates.toArray(new Calendar[dates.size()]);
                dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays1);

Answer (score 0):

For enabling specified dates in a calendar, you can use this [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

Here if you will see the DatePickerFragment in the sample. We are passing an array of calendar dates like this.

```
               Calendar[] days = new Calendar[13];
                for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++) {
                    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
                    day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i * 2);
                    days[i + 6] = day;
                }
               dpd.setSelectableDays(days);
```

We can create the array of calendar dates in specified format and pass that calendar dates array to the date picker dialog to enable it.

You can achieve your goal in similar way.

Comment: can u please send me the code by disabling any date

Answer (score -1):

At last found it.. how to disable specified dates in calendar..

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    String a = "26-07-2017";
                    java.util.Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = sdf.parse(a);
                        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
                        calendar = obj.dateToCalendar(date);
                        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();
                    dates.add(calendar);
                    Calendar[] disabledDays1 = dates.toArray(new Calendar[dates.size()]);
                    dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays1);

private Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
```

Comment: what is dpd? please always post complete code